# making more rows in a row of treeview!

Tags: python, pygtk

I wanna make sth like this in transmission: [link text]here[1](http://www.imagehost.ro/pict/072137214c34c961b42f5.png)
(also in pidgin too, Status under IDs)
can anyone show me a sample code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a TreeView with a custom CellRenderer.  Here's [some documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html) and [an example of the latter](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.045.htp).